# How to match condition IF in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this.

```
string strex = "Insert|Update|Delete"
```

I am retrieving another string as `string strex1 = "Insert"` (It may retrieve Update or Delete)
I need to match `strex1` with `strex` in "IF" condition in C#.

Do I need to split `strex` and match with `strex1`?

Answer (score 6):

The string you posted is [a regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) pattern that matches the words `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete`. Regular expressions are a *very* common way of specifying validation rules in web applications.

Regular expressions can express far more complex rules than a simple comparison. They're also far faster (think 10x) in validation scenarios than splitting. In a web application, that translates to using fewer servers to serve the same traffic.

You can use .NET's [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0) to match strings with that pattern, eg :

```
var strex = "Insert|Update|Delete";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input,strex))
{
....
}
```

This will create a new regular expression object each time. You can avoid this by creating a static Regex instance and reuse it. Regex is [thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0#thread-safety) which means there's no problem using the same instance from multiple threads :

```
static Regex _cmdRegex = new Regex("Insert|Update|Delete");
...
void MyMethod(string input)
{

    if(_cmdRegex.IsMatch(input))
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

The Regex class methods will match if the pattern appears anywhere in the pattern. `Regex.IsMatch("Insert1",strex)` will return `True`. If you want an exact match, you have to specify that the pattern starts at the beginning of the input with `^` and ends at the end with `$` :

```
static Regex _cmdRegex = new Regex("^(Insert|Update|Delete)$");
```

With this change, `_cmdRegex.IsMatch("Insert1")` will return false but `_cmdRegex.IsMatch("Insert")` will return true.

**Performance**

In this case a regular expression is a *lot* faster than splitting and trying exact matches. Think 10-100x over time. There are two reasons for this:

1. Strings are immutable, so *every* string modification operation like `Split()` will generate new temporary strings that have to be allocated and garbage collected. In a busy web application this adds up, eventually using up a lot of RAM and CPU for little or no benefit. One of the reasons ASP.NET Core is 10x times faster than the old ASP.NET is eliminating such substring operations wherever possible.
2. A regular expression is compiled into a program that performs matching in the most efficient way. When you use `Split().Any()` the program will compare the input with all the substrings even if it's obvious there's no possible match, eg because the first letter is `Z`. A Regex program on the other hand would only proceed if the first character was `I`, `U` or `D`

Answer (score 5):

Efficient way I can think of is using [string.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_)

```
if(strex.Contains($"{strex1}|") || strex.Contains($"|{strex1}"))
{
  //Your code goes here
}
```

---

Solution using Linq, [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) string `strex` by '|' and check `strex1` is present in an array or not, like

> Issue with below solution is pointed out by @PanagiotisKanavos in the
> comment.

Using [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0),

```
if(strex.Split('|').Any(x => x.Equals(strex1)))
{
  //Your code goes here
}
```

or using [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0),

```
if(strex.Split('|').Contains(strex1))
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

if you want to ignore case while comparing string then you can use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

```
if(strex.Split('|').Any(x => x.Equals(strex1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

---

[.NETFIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEwkSE)

Comment: This is very inefficient - it will create 3 new strings in every execution

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for pointing out the inefficiency in my code. I fixed your issue in my last solution, kindly check it.

Comment: Maybe just consider there's no real good reason to save them as a string that you just have to split every time...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I added fiddle for my solution. here is the link https://dotnetfiddle.net/wEwkSE

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know if OP is stuck with the input string being a non-static string or not. Can it hard-coded? No one knows. This solves the problem if it's not static.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I completely agree with your statement and added it in my answer as well

Comment: if(strex.Split('|').Any(x => x == strex1)) would be best solution but I would suggest to use equals method with ignore case instead of using == here.
i.e.
if(strex.Split('|').Any(x => x.Equals(strex1, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))

Comment: @BinodMahto, Thanks for your suggestion, I fixed it

Comment: Thanks Prasad. I tried your code. This is also working. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Guvera, if my solution worked for you, can you please go ahead and accept it by green tick.